# WSO2 ESB conector oracle c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, wso2

Estoy utilizando **WSO2** Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) para usarlo como bus de datos de **WSDL** ... Pero ahora me están pidiendo utilizar otro servicio que sea capaz de mandar una consulta con parametros, que desde mi aplicacion (**ASP.Net C#**) la llame pasandole los parámetros y esta sea capaz de devolverme el resultado para bindearlo a un gridview
Hasta ahora he visto WSO2 Governement que utiliza Oracle Bus Service pero ...

- **¿Puedo usar solamente ESB para lo que me están pidiendo o necesito OBLIGATORIAMENTE el otro?**

  Si es así:
- **¿Se pueden instalar las dos aplicaciones dentro del mismo servidor/maquina virtual sin ningún problema?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No evaluaste utilizar

[NServiceBus](http://docs.particular.net/platform/)

[MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/)

son alternnativas al service bus de Oracle

No veo que los parametros sean un problema ya que si implementas un service bus estos usan `queues` para desacoplar la comunicacion, los objetos son serializados